# redirect urls - possible?

Tags: url

I want to redirect http://abc.example.com to other external site abc.blog.com but i dont want to change the url from which i redirected. It should remain the same, i tried using dns but not working.

Kindly guide me with each and every step.

If its possible with htacces then how ?

Answer (score 4):

If you own `abc.example.com` you can set it up as a [`CNAME`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME) of `abc.blog.com`, which you'd need to configure with your domain name registrar. A `CNAME` makes a domain the alias of another (without redirecting), which is the functionality you're after.

You may need to configure the `abc.blog.com` website to accept `abc.example.com` as a valid host (most blogging providers like blogger support this). My blog (via my SO profile) is an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a proxy redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://someotherhost.tld/$0 [P]
```